# Images seperated with Huge space in between while downloading using Glide

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to show images after downloading them from server using Glide lib. Below is my layout. The issue is images are automatically adjusting space in between them (vertical space).If you see I did not keep any space and in xml preview, I can see both images are touching each other where as once it get downloaded from server, I could see almost half of screen size between textview and imageviews. How this space can be managed. I read many blogs and question but still not clear . pls advice.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/pad10">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textColor="@color/CadetBlue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/topm25"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this version of Glide, it's very good

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

simple example

```
Glide.with(context)
 .load("https://www.ejemplo.com/foto.png")
 .into(fotoImageView);
```

Example with options

```
Glide.with(context)
 .load("https://www.ejemplo.com/foto.png")
 .crossFade()
 .centerCrop()
 .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_temp_image)
 .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
 .thumbnail(0.5f)
 .into(fotoImageView);
```

In your case, you can change the sacleType of your imageView by centerCrop and in the same way use .centerCrop () in the Glide, if you want to use fitCenter also change the Glide by fitCenter ()
These properties can be found in the version of Glide that I put you up, luck!

with the `CrossFade()` method we can make the image appear with an imagination when it finishes loading

with `CenterCrop()` we make the image occupy all the available space of the ImageView

with `PlaceHolder(R.drawable.ic_temp_img)` we can put a temporary image while loading the image

with `diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)` we can configure the cahce strategy that we are going to use

Even if the image is very large with `thumbnail(0.5f)` it allows us to download a thumbnail while it is fully loaded

Comment: implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1' is latest version which does not have mentioned methods now stated by you.

Comment: Exactly, that's why you use this version implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0', there you have the methods that I wrote, which helps a lot!

Comment: @Panache Glide's latest version have these methods. You have to the Request method. See v4 docs. https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/placeholders.html above document is about requesting `Placeholder`.

Answer (score 0):

It worked using below trick

```
 Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point point = new Point();
        display.getSize(point);
        int width = point.x;


        ImageView im1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        ImageView im2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image2);


        im1.getLayoutParams().width = (width * 90) / 100;
        im2.getLayoutParams().width = (width * 90) / 100;
```